# IronPython SqlClient CommandType?

Tags: .net, ironpython, sqlclient

I'm trying to run a stored proc from iron python but having trouble setting the CommandType:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System')
clr.AddReference('System.IO')
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
from System import Console as cns
from System.Data import SqlClient as sql
```

I've tested code for the Sql connection and run a simple select query to verify that I can get a working connection, so that's passed into this function as ''con''

```
def get_cols_for(con, table):
    cols = {}
    cmd = sql.SqlCommand("sp_columns", con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(sql.SqlParameter("@table_name", "EQUIPMENT")) 
    sp = sql.SqlCommand.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    while rdr.Read():
        cols[str(rdr[3])]=(str(rdr[5]),int(rdr[7])) # ColumnName @ 3, TypeName @ 5
    rdr.Close()
    return cols
```

The intellisense suggests StoredProcedure as a CommandType member automatically, so I'm pretty sure it's actually there, but when I run this code I get the following complaint:

{"'getset_descriptor' object has no attribute 'StoredProcedure'"}

when I execute the line *sp = sql.SqlCommand.CommandType.StoredProcedure*

How does one go about setting the CommandType?

Incidentally, if I just use this form, it works ok:

```
 cmd = sql.SqlCommand("exec sp_columns @table_name='%s'" % table, con)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it isn't imported. 
If you import it via

```
from System.Data import CommandType as cmdType
```

it works:

```
>>>cmdType.__doc__
```

returns:

> Specifies how a command string is interpreted. enum 
>   CommandType, values: StoredProcedure (4), TableDirect (512), Text (1)

Please also note that you, according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.commandtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), should also set the `CommandText` property to the name of the stored procedure.

Comment: Yes, thanks tobsen, I had tried to import CommandType from System.Data.SqlCommand since it appears in that library, but it does work the way you import it.  BTW, the CommandText is set by the SqlCommand constructor, so there's no need to set it separately.  I could have said cmd = sql.SqlCommand(con), then set it as the next step, e.g. cmd.CommandText="sp_columns" too.